# How to match the KeyId,if keyId will be match remove from array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
        /**
         * @Summary: setUserAccessB  function, to get detail of the shared product.
         * @param: event, index, userObj
         * @return: callback(response)
         * @Description:
         */
        $scope.buyerObjectList            = [];
        $scope.productDBList              = [];
        $scope.productObjectForShareModal = null;

        $scope.countConnectedBuyer  = 0;
        $scope.setUserAccessB = function(index, isChecked, keyId) {
          if(isChecked) {
            $scope.buyerObjectList.push(keyId);
            $scope.countConnectedBuyer ++;
          } else {
            var index = $scope.buyerObjectList.indexOf(keyId);
            $scope.buyerObjectList.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.countConnectedBuyer --;
          }
        }

            /**
             * @Summary: checkAllConnectedUser function, to create album
             * @param: index, productObj
             * @return: callback(response)
             * @Description:
             */
            $scope.checkAllBuyerKeyId      = [];
            $scope.buyerObj                = [];
            $scope.intermediaryObjectList  = [];
            $scope.checkAllConnectedUser = function(isChecked) {
              if(isChecked) {
                if ($scope.selectedAll) {
                  $scope.selectedAll = false;
                } else {
                  $scope.selectedAll = true;
                } 
                angular.forEach($scope.buyerRelationDtoForModal.buyerDtos, function (buyerObj) {
                  buyerObj.select = $scope.selectedAll;
                  //IF ID WILL BE EXIST IN THE ARRAY NOT PSUH THE KEYID
                  if($scope.buyerObjectList.indexOf(buyerObj.userTypeDto.keyId) == -1) {
                    $scope.buyerObjectList.push(buyerObj.userTypeDto.keyId);
                    $scope.countConnectedBuyer ++;
                  }
                });

               } else {
                  $scope.selectedAll  = false;
                  //USED FOR UNCHECK ALL THE DATA ONE- BY-ONE
                  angular.forEach($scope.buyerRelationDtoForModal.buyerDtos, function (buyerObj) {
                    buyerObj.select = $scope.selectedAll;
                    var index = $scope.buyerObjectList.indexOf(buyerObj.userTypeDto.keyId);
                    $scope.buyerObjectList.splice(index, 1);
                    if($scope.buyerObjectList.length == 0) {
                      $scope.countConnectedBuyer = 0;
                    } else {
                      $scope.countConnectedBuyer --;
                    }
                  });
                }
             }
```

```html
<div id="buyer" class="w3-container userSection">
  <div class="checkbox w3-margin" ng-if="buyerRelationDtoForModal.buyerDtos.length > 0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll"  ngclick="checkAllConnectedUser(selectedAll)"/>Check All
      </label>
      <span class="w3-right" ng-if="countConnectedBuyer">
        <h5>You are selecting {{countConnectedBuyer}} buyers!</h5>
      </span>
    </div>
      <div class="w3-row userObjRow" ng-repeat="buyerObj in buyerListTemp = (buyerRelationDtoForModal.buyerDtos) track by $index" 
        ng-if="checkIfBuyerIsSharedAlready(buyerObj.keyId) && buyerObj.userAccessType == 'private'">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 productDetailsWrap item_info" >
          <div class="w3-row ng-cloak">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label id="shareUserSection">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="buyerObj.select" 
                  ng-click ="setUserAccessB($index, buyerObj.select, buyerObj.userTypeDto.keyId)"/>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user w3-text-black"></i>
                    {{buyerObj.personName}} 
                  <span class="w3-text-teal">
                    {{buyerObj.userTypeDto.userTypeAddressDtos[0].city}}
                  </span>  
              </label> -&nbsp; 
              <span class="w3-tag w3-teal w3-round w3-small">
                &nbsp;{{buyerObj.userTypeDto.userType}}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

I have to share product with user and I have to list- 1st connected user list for share product with user and 2nd is the shared user list(shared product list) if I have click on  the  check all checkbox here all checkbox will be check but at time I have to remove 1 user at  a time and click on the shared user list.now again I click on the check all checkbox here only 1 user found and I will get 1 update user but here I will be found all user again because I have iterate all the list again, 
angular.forEach($scope.buyerRelationDtoForModal.buyerDtos) - here I will remove the match keyID and updated the 1 user how  to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you try rewriting a bit? I've read several times but am not quite sure I am following :(

Comment: I agree, put some effort in your question. It's painfully hard to read, let alone understand.

Comment: Hello sir,if the user check the checkALL here every time all KeyID will be push again in the array but i have to push only those id that is not exist in the another array?